# Recuperate digit and characters after "_"

Tags: php, regex, match

I want to extract with a regex every digit and characters that are after an underscore. I tried `\_\d{1,3}`  but it didn't work at all.

Here is a sample of a chain that I need to manipulate: `R_31_1_35_6a`.

Here is the result I want:

```
array('31', '1', '35', '6a');
```

Comment: Would be better to just `explode('_')` and `array_filter()` for those whose first char is a digit.

Comment: Maybe my English is just that bad, but what does "recuperate" mean in that context?

Comment: @feeela probably closer to "recover" here, or more accurately "get" :-)

Comment: @feela: Recuperate is like retrieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode to separate the string by underscores:

```
$string = "R_31_1_35_6a";
$result = explode('_', $string);
```

And then you can drop the first entry which is 'R' in this case:

```
array_shift($result);
```

This returns your expected result:

```
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @NullUserException Please re-read the question, this is what is asked for: "Every digit and characters that are after an underscore". Everything after implies even if the first is a number it does not matter.

Comment: Then it's also implied that anything that comes after an underscore that's not a digit and character (which I assume means "letter") should be discarded. I removed the downvote, but the question *is* ambiguous.

Comment: @NullUserException Your comment is wrong as PHP returns an empty element as first array entry if the string starts with an underscore! `var_dump( explode('_', '_R_31_1_35_6a' ) );`

Comment: I need a regEx because i'm gonna verify it like 
if(preg_match($patern, $string, $result)){ then... }

Comment: @feela That's not what I'm talking about; read my comment under the question and you'll understand.

Comment: @Hulk In that case, please elaborate on your question, so the context is clearer. What is the regex checking for?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "R_31_1_35_6a";
$cleanedString = strstr("_", $string);
$result = explode('_', $cleanedString);
print_r($result); // Ignore the first (zeroth) element as it's the prefix value
```

Comment: This will return also 'R' and '6a', which need to be treated/discarded furtherly

Comment: @Damien Pirsy …but `6a` is in the "wishlist" of the question poster;

Comment: Yep, you're right, I overlooked! The title said only "digit", that confused me

Comment: @hafichuk You need to strip the first element, because it is not "after an underscore".

Comment: I dont want the R.. just digit and characters that are AFTER the underscore

Comment: @Hulk Have a look at my answer below, using array_shift($array) removes the first element, so you have what you want.

Comment: FWIW, `echo` is incorrect here; `var_dump` is what you're after.

Comment: It needs to be a regular expression because i want to verify it like : if(preg_match($patern, $string, $result)){then..}

Comment: You just start evaluating the array at index 1 instead of zero, or use `array_shift` to push it off the stack.

Comment: @Hulk with respect to your comment about requiring preg_match, why bother is explode gives you the same result. Your OP stated you wanted an array.